# SVG convert polygon to curves conversion in Javascript

Tags: computational-geometry, curve-fitting

How can I convert a polygon shape to a curve in JS/SVG?

I have seen this solution: http://jsdraw2d.jsfiction.com/ but this seems to be dealing with VML and not SVG.

Is there something out-of-the-box that can be used to accurately convert a polygon to a path without ANY loss of quality?

When I say path I don't mean a path with >4000 nodes. I mean a path with curves instead of many nodes. Which in turn means reducing the node count since the polygons would be converted into curves.

Comment: If I recall correctly the freehand tool in SVG-Edit/Method Draw has something similar to this, it creates curves from a set of points (your mouse movement). I don't have time to dive in and find it, just a heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that while polygonizing, you sampled points on the curve, and joined them with straight lines.
The reverse process is curve fitting.

You want to do a "Hermite fitting of curve through a set of points". A little search will help you out.

There are more such fitting algorithms. This is maths based and the under the hood solution to what you want. This is also how most such problems are solved.

If you want a quick solution, you would have to find a library that does it for you. i.e take a set of points, and fits a curve through them.

**Note:** I assume that fitting a curve through more than 4000 nodes is going to be costly. You could try it and see the performance for yourself, as I am not sure how costly would this be. But, I would suggest that if you needed to maintain the accuracy of your boolean operation. You should not have polygonized them at first. It is just redundancy of efforts to lose accuracy only to gain it back. Boolean set operations can be be done, and are done, without polygonizing the curve data.

**Links** for reference, and demos

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~baker/java/hoefer/Spline.htm

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~baker/java/hoefer/Lagrange.htm

Comment: indeed the most correct solution is to use a ''curvy'' boolean operations algorithm from the very beginning. However i am quite convinced that such algorithms are highly unreliable and they do not really handle all polygon cases(self intersecting and some other forms). I used Clipper from Angus Johnson which is the fastest, most reliable and handles almost all polygon cases. The only disadvantage is that it does not handle curves. Although in my case the boolean operations must happen in real time, the curve fitting is a one-time thing, only when the user decides to export the file.

Comment: We are quite used to seeing polygonal problems. Lots of solutions are available, mainly because the gaming and graphics industry uses a lot of polylines. In industries like CAD and modelling, the requirement is more towards accuracy and as such a lot of methods and research are already present for curvy intersection problems. It is a tad bit harder, at time slower, but it exists for sure. I work on one. :)

Comment: The problem is just harder, as an analogy , its easy to juggle 2 balls than 3. The striaght line problem has in a way 2 dimensions, while the curve problem has 3. It exists, is reliable and the relevant research and algorithms are there. Its just not as simple as the straight line approach . :)

Comment: :) yes. The one i work on(ACIS) is licensed. Handling spline curves are the basic building blocks for geometry kernel libraries. You may check CGAL, which is free and i assume will have these things.

Comment: The links are more of a demo for spline interpolation in general. It doesnt really take a feed of points, you have to supply them through mouse movements..

There is a bit of maths involved, if you like what you see, you would probably have to search some library that does it or code it yourself.

Comment: I don't really have to code these things coz ACIS already has everything. I use it :)